# Java ESC/POS Image full width Printing

Tags: java, image, printing, escpos

I'm trying to print image using Esc/Pos command which given in [this blog](http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html). It's printing fine but i want to align  image to center and fit to paper size.
I print this image:

[image]

and output like this:

[image]

My code same as [this blog post](http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html)
but I change `getPixelsSlow(BufferedImage image)` method to this two method because Android doesn't have `BufferedImage` class.

```
private int[][] getPixelsSlow(Bitmap image) {
  int width = image.getWidth();
  int height = image.getHeight();
  int[][] result = new int[height][width];
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      result[row][col] = getRGB(image, col, row);
     }
   }

  return result;
}

private int getRGB(Bitmap bmpOriginal, int col, int row) {
   // get one pixel color
   int pixel = bmpOriginal.getPixel(col, row);
   // retrieve color of all channels
   int R = Color.red(pixel);
   int G = Color.green(pixel);
   int B = Color.blue(pixel);
   return Color.rgb(R, G, B);
}
```

How can I print image in full width?. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you search on the web, you will find a library or method that converts the vertical and horizontal size of the image data and converts it according to the maximum width of the paper to be printed.

However, since the size of the original data is as small as 113 width and 48 height, those conversions will cause jaggy and less artistic.

It is better to create and use image data that matches the width of the paper to be printed in advance.

For example, if you use GIMP to enlarge the width to 512 and the height to 217 as JPEG, it will be as follows.
[image: enlargeGIMP]

Or if you enlarge it to the same size with Windows Paint and then convert it to BMP in monochrome binary format, it will be as follows.
[image: enlargemonochromePaint]

Rather than performing such conversion, it will be much more beautiful and effective for marketing etc. if you create a design by specifying the width 512 from the beginning.